# How may ways to implement interaction be Google Sreadsheet and Google App Engine

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-sheets

Currently, we use JSon string to communicate between our Google Spreadsheet application and our services hosted at Google App Engine. When the JSon data object becomes large, the communication becomes very slow.

My question is what are the other ways to implement the interaction/communication for large data object between Google Spreadsheet and Google App Engine.

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

That would be ScriptDb. For Google Apps for Business it can contain 200 MB of data.
See reference for code examples, in combination with Google Spreadsheet.

See also the site of [Bruce McPherson](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112066118406610145134/about). He wrote a library around the ScriptDb: [Using ScriptDb](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/scriptdb)

Reference: [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb)